# How to iterate data from mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Im trying to iterate two objects from mongoose on ejs but only one object show up and i somehow other one is not showing?

```
<% db.forEach( function(db) { %>
<%=db.title %> <% db.detail %>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: I forgot to put equal sign and for some reason i wasn't working before but now it does and im kinda confuse how its working.

Comment: When you want to print something in your `ejs` file you need to use `<%= anything %>` and when you want to check condition or use loops you just use `<% if(anything) %> {`  @Hamza

Comment: Yea thanks man already solved it had to go through documentation.